# Pass on the current routes active ID to a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have done several things with components and they are absolutely awesome, but now i've ran into a little problem I cant seem to solve, and google returns only vague answers, as it all is pretty new.

I want to pass in the ID of the current active controller/model that has been selected.

As the component is isolated from the rest of the application, the standard ways of using `controllerFor` doesn't seem to work.

I can pass in integers to my component using the `ApplicationController`, but I can't seem to find a way to pass in the current id. I have made an ugly workaround that parses the current url and splits by `/`, but thats not the ember way. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this fiddle addresses your concerns. The correct approach I believe is creating a binding for the component.

http://jsfiddle.net/ahaurw01/CB2WS/1/

The essence of the approach is having a component that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-comp">
  The id is {{id}}.
</script>
```

And using it in this manner:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="thing">
  {{my-comp id=model.id}}
</script>
```

The `model` property is present on every `ObjectController` and you can bind to the id of the model.